# How to Parse a DateTime in a specific timezone in .Net 6 ( Australia / Sydney )

Tags: .net, datetime, f#, .net-6.0

I have a Datetime string that I want to parse as a specific time zone, taking into account daylight savings

For example - I have a string:  ( using F# but uses same libraries )
let dateString = "20/12/2022 11:26:34"

The timezone is Australia Sydney - and I think that timezone is sometimes easter standard time and sometimes eastern daylight time.

Is there any way I can specifically parse a date to Sydney time in a way that will automatically convert to the correct DateTime taking into account daylight savings?

Comment: I think [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/) was created for exactly this problem

Comment: Thanks - but the docs are horrible for noda time!  not straightforward at all.

Answer (score 1):

`TimeZoneInfo` and `DateTimeOffset` can be used together for this.

```ml
open System

let sydneyTimezone: TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("AET")

(* The date with unspecified timezone info *)
let unspecifiedDate: DateTime = DateTime.Parse("20/12/2022 11:26:34")

(* Uses the given date to determine the correct offset (10 or 11 hours depending on daylight) *)
let offset: TimeSpan = sydneyTimezone.GetUtcOffset(unspecifiedDate)

(* The date with the correct offset *)
let dateWithOffset: DateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset(unspecifiedDate, offset)

(* If you want the corresponding UTC *)
let dateUtc: DateTime = dateWithOffset.UtcDateTime
```

Edit: added the types for clarity.

Comment: is there an inherent problem here?
when u go "GetUtcOffset" the unspecified date is interpreted as a datetime in the current local timezone? also because DST gives coincident time values (when there is no UTC offset present), there is an hour a year when it seems (to me) impossible to actually know what the time is

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd In GetUtcOffset, the unspecified date is interpreted as a datetime in the Sydney timezone.

Comment: ah yes...sorry. u are right...do u know what happens to times when they are in the time that overlap?

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd And to handle the case where you're during a DST transition, there's GetAmbiguousTimeOffsets. It returns an array of TimeSpans. It will contain 1 item most of the time, 0 item in the transition from winter to summer and 2 items in the transition from summer to winter. (I don't know what GetUtcOffset does in these cases though)

Comment: @Tarmil .  I don't think this will work.  I have a date that is not UTC - it is actually already in the Sydney time zone ( as a string ) .  I think your code is allowing for a UTC date / time